# ¿Conocen un paquete de mapas para Colombia en R?

Tags: r

alguien conoce un paquete de mapas para Colombia en R. Para trabajar datos espaciales en epidemiología.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a [es.so], te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Tu pregunta no es sobre un problema específico de programación. Te invito a leer [¿Sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para mayor información. Saludos

Comment: Si haces una búsqueda con las palabras clave `mapa` o `cartografía` en la etiqueta R de este sitio encontrarás varias preguntas y respuestas sobre el tema que podrían ayudarte a comenzar a trabajar con cartografía en R. Puedes encontrar shapefiles de Colombia (y todo el mundo) en https://gadm.org/download_country_v3.html Tienen shapefiles subdivididos por país, departamento y municipio y una licencia gratuita para uso no comercial (académico). Además están en un sistema de coordenadas fácil de usar.

Answer (score 2):

Hola Simon creo tener un ejemplo que le pueda servir. La página [GeoNames](https://www.geonames.org/) encontrara una base de datos geográfica la cual contiene todos los países que se pueden descargar de forma gratuita. Solo debe crear una cuenta. Por ejemplo tomemos la 5 ciudades principales de Colombia.

```
#Aquí debe colocar el nombre de usuario de su cuenta en GeoNames
options(geonamesUsername="usuario")
library(geonames)

# Lista de las ciudades de Colombia 
ciudades <- c("Bogota", "Medellin", "Cartagena", "Barranquilla", "Cali")

# conveninence function to look up and format results  
GNsearchAF <- function(city) {  
  res <- GNsearch(name=city, country="CO")  
  return(res[1,c("name","adminName1","population","lng","lat")])  
}

# loop over city names and reformat 
GNresult <- do.call(rbind, lapply(ciudades, GNsearchAF))
colnames(GNresult) <- c("Ciudad", "Departamento", "Población", "Longitud", "Latitud")
GNresult[,3:5] <- sapply(GNresult[,3:5], as.numeric)
```

Como vemos el resultado es la Ciudad, Departamento, Población, Latitud y Longitud, con lo cual se pueden georeferenciar.

```
GNresult
                Ciudad    Departamento Población  Longitud  Latitud
    1           Bogotá     Bogota D.C.   7674366 -74.08175  4.60971
    2         Medellín       Antioquia   1999979 -75.56359  6.25184
    3        Cartagena         Bolívar    952024 -75.51444 10.39972
    4     Barranquilla       Atlántico   1380425 -74.78132 10.96854
    5 Santiago de Cali Valle del Cauca   2392877 -76.52250  3.43722
```

Como su interés es estudiar el comportamiento de las epidemias, entonces podría cambiar la variable **Población**, por el nombre de una enfermedad de interés. Por ejemplo una enfermedad muy común en las zonas tropicales de Colombia es el dengue. (Utilice número de infectados por dengue en el 2018).

```
library(leaflet)
leaflet(GNresult) %>% addTiles() %>%
  addCircles(lng = ~Longitud, lat = ~Latitud, weight = 15,
             radius = ~sqrt(Población)*10, popup = ~Ciudad)
```

Finalmente utilizando el paquete *leaflet*, crear mapas interactivos para el estudio de las epidemias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Rafael muchas gracias. Esto me ha ayudado mucho.

Answer (score 1):

Hay una alternativa de librería que nos puede ser útil:

```
devtools::install_github("nebulae-co/colmaps", force = TRUE)
library(colmaps)
library(ggplot2)
library(sp)
```

Para accesar un departamento se utilizan los codigos de la division político administrativa dada por el Departamento Administrativo Nacional de Estadística (divipola - DANE), por ejemplo cundinamarca:

```
mapacundinamarca <- departamentos[departamentos$id == 25,]"
```

Para los municipios:

```
cundinamarca <- municipios[municipios@data$id_depto == 25,]
```

Genera un objeto que permite accesar municipio por municipio del departamento de cundinamarca.

Está poco documentado, pero funciona bien.

```
colmap(map = cundinamarca, map_id = 'region', autocomplete = TRUE)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es factible asignar color y leyenda a cada municipio o departamento.